# Compare string to string gives false when it should be true in python

Tags: python, string, compare, newline

I was doing a simple compare string and it has come up false.

I think it is comparing "\n" character at the end of the line but not to sure.

Interestingly it does throw TRUE when you compare the last name of each list.

**PSEUDO**

> 1. Create loop to check each file from the list of objects
> 2. Check list of boys names .. boys.txt
> 3. Check list of girls names .. girls.txt
> 4. Output result if in list and index position (not allowed to use slice)

Here is the code
**boys.txt**

```
john
paul
andrew
judas
archie
scot
```

**girls.txt**

```
cassie
sam
josie
nadine
cathy
```

**nameSearch.py**

```
def read_list(fileToOpen):
    thisFile = fileToOpen + ".txt"
    filez = open(thisFile, "r")    
    names = filez.readlines()    
    filez.close()
    
    return names

def findName(name, nameList):
    count = 0
    pos = -1

    for thisName in nameList:
        print("Comparing", name, "to", thisName)

        if name == thisName:
            print (name, "has been found !!!")
            pos = count
        else:
            print(name, "does not compare to", thisName)
            count += 1

    return

filesList = ["boys", "girls"]

name = input("What is the name of the child ? ")

for thisFile in filesList:
    nameList = read_list(thisFile)
    result = findName(name,nameList)
```

**RESULT by searching John**

```
What is the name of the child ? john
Comparing john to john

john does not compare to john

Comparing john to paul

john does not compare to paul

Comparing john to andrew

john does not compare to andrew

Comparing john to judas

john does not compare to judas

Comparing john to archie

john does not compare to archie

Comparing john to scot
john does not compare to scot
```

**Result by searching scot**

```
What is the name of the child ? scot
Comparing scot to john

scot does not compare to john

Comparing scot to paul

scot does not compare to paul

Comparing scot to andrew

scot does not compare to andrew

Comparing scot to judas

scot does not compare to judas

Comparing scot to archie

scot does not compare to archie

Comparing scot to scot
scot has been found !!!
```

Comment: _"I think it is comparing "\n" character at the end of the line but not to sure."_ I like that theory :-) I suggest you test it out. Try putting `print(nameList)` just below your `read_list` call, and see if any of the entries have newlines at the end.

Comment: ['john\n', 'paul\n', 'andrew\n', 'judas\n', 'archie\n', 'scot'] .. yes it is .. so I have to do thisName.strip("\n") i think .. will update in a second

Comment: Yes that was the solution to add aName = thisName.strip("\n") just after the for loop starts in the findName function.  Hope this helps others :-)

Answer (score 0):

Solution was easy enough, I updated

```
def findName(name, nameList):
    count = 0
    pos = -1

    for thisName in nameList:
        print("Comparing", name, "to", thisName)
        aName = thisName.strip("\n")  ## <-- added this line
        if name == aName:
            print (name, "has been found !!!")
            pos = count
        else:
            print(name, "does not compare to", aName)
            count += 1

    return
```